# Error Importing External Class in Vue Component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, import, vue-component

I am trying to import an external javascript file that contains a Form Class to Vue Component.

File Structure:

```
js
- components
-- dashboard
--- dashboard.vue
- app.js
- form.js
```

I already tried this but still returns error.

```
import Form from '../../form.js'
import Form from '../../form'
import Form from './form'
```

form.js

```
export default class Form{
    // Code Here
}
```

dashboard.vue

```
<template>
    // Code
</template>

<script>
   import Form from '../../form.js' <- not working
   import Form from '../../form'    <- not working
   import Form from './form'        <- not working

   export default{
      name: 'Dashboard',
      data(){
         return [
           form: new Form({
               field1: '',
               ...
           })
         ]
      }
   }
</script>
```

Please Help Thank You So Much

Comment: Is `form.js` outside of `js` folder? I think it should be `import Form from '../../../form.js'
`

Comment: `form.js` is inside the `js` folder sorry for the confusion. will update the description.

Comment: Just to be sure: What does the error message say? Do other imports work? The code looks good to me. ```import Form from '../../form.js'``` should work, I'd guess.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to export the class you want to use.

```
export class className {}
```

and

```
import {className} from '<file path>';
```